# Using Java Stream to check whether 2 strings have any common character in a single statement

Tags: java, java-stream

Below code has s1 and s2. This function will return "YES" if there is any matching character, otherwise "NO".

```
    public String checkIfStringsHaveSubStrings(String s1, String s2) {
        boolean[] alphabets = new boolean[26];
        s1.chars().forEach(s -> alphabets[s - 97] = true);
        return s2.chars().filter(s -> alphabets[s - 97]).count() > 0 ? "YES" : "NO";
    }
```

I am expecting a single statement using stream which doesn't require extra variable to be declared, unlike in my case i have used the additional space as shown below.

> boolean[] alphabets = new boolean[26];

Expecting a single line, short and efficient statement using Stream.

**There could be several easy approaches, But i wanted to use streams as i am learning it.**

Comment: Don’t use magic numbers like `97` or `26` in your code. Use `'a'` instead of `97` and `'z'-'a'+1` instead of `26`. That way, the meaning is obvious while you don’t give away anything, as the compiled code will be identical. But instead of `filter(…).count() > 0`, you should use `.anyMatch(…)` which can stop at the first match, which is more efficient than counting all matches. That’s short enough and efficient. Writing it in one line won’t improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
public static String checkIfStringsHaveSubStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    return s2.chars().anyMatch(c -> s1.indexOf((char) c) >= 0) ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

Of course that's not the most efficient way.

Comment: At least for using streams only, i suppose for smaller strings your version works just fine, `boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet())` followed by `s1.stream().anyMatch()` is slower. But what you meant could also imply not using streams for operations like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not bad performance-wise. Writing everything into one statement is not necessarily an improvement. Denser source code does not imply better performance.

One thing you should improve, is not to count all occurrences, when you only want to know whether there are any occurrences. Using `anyMatch` expresses the intent and will be more efficient, as `anyMatch` can stop searching as soon as a match has been found:

```
public String checkIfStringsHaveSubStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    boolean[] alphabets = new boolean['z' - 'a' + 1];
    s1.chars().forEach(s -> alphabets[s - 'a'] = true);
    return s2.chars().anyMatch(s -> alphabets[s - 'a'])? "YES": "NO";
}
```

A temporary `boolean[]` array with 26 elements is nothing to worry about, but if you insist on reducing the memory consumption, 26 truth values can be expressed as 26 bits, which fit into a single `int` value.

```
public String checkIfStringsHaveSubStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    int alphabets = s1.chars().map(c -> 1 << c - 'a').reduce(0, (a,b) -> a | b);
    return s2.chars().map(c -> 1 << c - 'a').anyMatch(i -> (i & alphabets) != 0)?"YES":"NO";
}
```

If you want to express this as a single statement at all cost, you can use

```
public String checkIfStringsHaveSubStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    return (s1.chars().map(c -> 1 << c - 'a').reduce(0, (a,b) -> a | b)
         &  s2.chars().map(c -> 1 << c - 'a').reduce(0, (a,b) -> a | b)) != 0? "YES": "NO";
}
```

But it should be obvious that now that it is processing the entire second string instead of stopping at the first match, it is less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    System.out.println(
            checkIfStringsHaveSubStrings("abcde", "xyz"));
    System.out.println(
            checkIfStringsHaveSubStrings("abcxde", "xyz"));



    public static String checkIfStringsHaveSubStrings(String s1,
            String s2) {
        return s1.chars().filter(c -> s2.contains((char) c + ""))
                .count() == 0L ? "NO" : "YES";
    }
```

And here is an alternative if you have Java 11 (the `isEmpty()` method).  Probably best of the two since it stops looking as soon as it finds one.

```
    public static String checkIfStringsHaveSubStrings(String s1,
            String s2) {
        return s1.chars().filter(c -> s2.contains((char) c + ""))
              .findFirst().isEmpty() ? "NO" : "YES";
    }
```